# Find Maximum Item in the List

Tags: java

I am facing a problem in finding the maximum item in the list! Suppose that i have a List

```
 List db_list=new List();
    db_list.add("0.5 150 A");

    db_list.add("0.3 120 B");

    db_list.add("0.1 250 C");
    db_list.add("0.7 100 C");
```

and i want to find the maximum item in the list:

```
    double m=Double.parseDouble(db_list.getItem(0).split("\\s")[0]);
    int Loc=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < db_list.getItemCount(); i++) {
        if (Double.parseDouble(db_list.getItem(i).split("\\s")[0])>m) {
            Loc+=1;
            m=Double.parseDouble(db_list.getItem(i).split("\\s")[0]);

        }
    }

    System.out.println("The Maximum is: "+db_list.getItem(Loc));
```

so that the maximum item should be "0.7 100 C"!
What is any problem in this logic can anybody figure out my blunder I am getting confused for last hours Thanks

Comment: use a `Comparator` instead

Comment: Put the `Loc+=1` out of the `if` statement

Comment: What is `List`? Have you written your own class called `List`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you want the location of the largest variable, not how many times you found a larger value.

```
Loc = i;
```

This is where using a debugger would have helped you find the problem in minutes.

For your interest, this how it could be written.

```
static double firstValue(String s) {
    return Double.parseDouble(s.split("\\s", 2)[0]);
}

double max = firstValue(db_list.getItem(0));
int loc = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < db_list.getItemCount(); i++) {
    double next = firstValue(db_list.getItem(i));
    if (next > max) {
        loc = i;
        max = next;
    }
}

System.out.println("The Maximum is: " + max + " at " + loc);
```

I also suggest you use the standard `List` class `ArrayList` in future.

Comment: I think you mean `double next = firstValue(db_list.getItem(i));`